# Any known cases of a person appearing in one reality TV show as having one career but later in another reality TV show as having a different career?

Tags: casting, reality-tv

This question is ***not*** about following types of reality TV shows:

1. "Big Brother" or "Jersey Shore" were the portrayed individuals are recognized as "actors"/"participants".
2. "Cops" where the portrayed individuals are in jobs and situations that are not easily staged.

What this question is about are reality TV shows like "Big Rig Bounty Hunters", "Storage Wars", "Shipping Wars", "Auction Hunters", and the like... shows that portray individuals earning money from careers and situations that might well be staged.

Are there any known cases where a person from one of these reality TV shows has been portrayed as having a different career in another reality TV show?

Comment: The American public is dumb, but they're not idiots.  Any show doing this would come under scrutiny and would be off the air faster than you can say "Ru-Paul's Drag Race".

Comment: @JohnnyBones _Ru-Paul's Drag Race_ actually has 6 seasons, and the 7th starts in March. It currently has a [7.9 star rating on IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1353056/episodes?season=7&ref_=tt_eps_sn_7).

Comment: That's awesome, but I'm a little sad that you know that.  :oD  My comment wasn't meant to infer that RPDR was off the air, I was just pulling out some random Reality TV show's name.

Comment: Barry Weiss went from buyer in _Storage Wars_ to appraiser in _Barry'd Treasure_, but that's probably not what you mean, is it?